# The set $\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{t\}$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^{n}$ for any $t\in\Bbb R$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, riemann-integration

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. We say $A$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^n$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a covering $Q_1,Q_2,...$ of $A$ by countably many rectangles such that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i)<\epsilon
> $$
> If this inequality holds, we often say that the total volume of the rectangles $Q_1,Q_2,...$ is less than $\epsilon$.

**Statement**

The set $\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{t\}$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ for any $t\in\Bbb R$

Unfortunately I don't be able to prove the statement so I ask to do it. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \{t\}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, right? :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Surely! Now I edit the title: excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the rectangles $Q_i = [-i, i]^{n - 1} \times [t - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n + 1} i^{n - 1} 2^i}, t + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n + 1}i^{n - 1} 2^i}]$. Then $Q_i$ has volume $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i + 1}}$, so $\sum v(Q_i) = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll stick to $t=0$.

If one allows rectangles of zero "height" as rectangles, then one can cover
$\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ by rectangles $[-N,N]^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ for $N\in N$.

If one doesn't, use instead $[-N,N]^{n-1}\times[0,\epsilon/((2N)^{n-1}2^N)]$.