# If $m<n$ then the embedding of $\Bbb R^m$ hase measure zero in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. We say $A$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^n$ iffor every $\epsilon>0$, there is a covering $Q_1,\,Q_2,...$ of $A$ by countably many rectangles such that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i)<\epsilon
> $$
> If this inequality holds, we often say that the total volume of hte rectangles $Q_1,Q_2,...$ is less than $\epsilon$.
>
> **Lemma**
>
> Let be $\mathfrak{X}:=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ a collection of topological spaces. So if $J\subseteq I$ then $X_J:=\Pi_{j\in J}X_j$ is embeddable in $X_I:=\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$.
>
> *Proof*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784919/for-any-collection-mathfrakx-x-ii-in-i-if-j-subseteq-i-then-pi-j).
>
> **Corollary**
>
> The subset $\Bbb R^m\times\{t_{m+1}\}\times...\times\{t_{m+(n-m)}\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$ for any $m<n$.
>
> **Lemma**
>
> The subset $\Bbb R^m\times\{t_{m+1}\}\times...\times\{t_{m+(n-m)}\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$ has measure zero in $\Bbb R^n$.

Well the user Doctor Who showed to me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788240/the-set-bbb-rn-1-times-t-has-measure-zero-in-bbb-rn-for-any-t-in) that this lemma is true in the case where $ m: = (n-1) $ so I tried to generalize the proof he gave.

> *Proof*. So for any $\epsilon>0$ the collection
> $$
> \mathcal C:=\{[-i,i]^m\times[t_{m+1}-\epsilon,t_{m+1}+\epsilon]\times...\times[t_n-\epsilon,t_n+\epsilon]:i=1,2,...\}
> $$
> is clearly a rectangular and countable cover of  $\Bbb R^m\times\{t_{m+1}\}\times...\times\{t_n\}$ that has total volume $(2i)^m\cdot (2\cdot \epsilon)^{n-m}$ so that if we find $\xi\in\Bbb R$ such that
> $$
> (2i)^m\cdot\biggr(\frac{2\epsilon}{\xi}\biggr)^{n-m}=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-m}}
> $$
> then clearly the collection
> $$
> \mathcal Q:=\Biggr\{\big[-i,i\big]^m\times\biggr[t_{m+1}-\frac{\epsilon}\xi,t_{m+1}+\frac{\epsilon}\xi\biggr]\times...\times\biggr[t_n-\frac{\epsilon}\xi,t_n+\frac{\epsilon}\xi\biggr]:i=1,2,...\Biggr\}
> $$
> is a rectangular and countable cover of $\Bbb R^m\times\{t_{m+1}\}\times...\times\{t_n\}$ of total volume less than $\epsilon$. So we pick $\xi=(2i)^m\cdot\epsilon^{n-m-1}$ and the lemma follows.

So I ask if my proof is correct and if not I ask to prove the last lemma. In particular I doubt that my proof is uncorrect because in the answer of the user Doctor Who the $\epsilon$ quantity was only at the numerator of $(n-m)$ last factors of each rectangule. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The case $m=n-1$ is sufficient. If $m<n-1$ the set in question is a subset of an $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane, which has measure zero.

Comment: @AnginaSeng unfortunately I use what you said to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797598/any-linear-subspace-has-measure-zero) so that I can't use your argument.

Comment: Of course you can; it's an immediate corollary of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788240/the-set-bbb-rn-1-times-t-has-measure-zero-in-bbb-rn-for-any-t-in

Comment: @AnginaSeng Okay, so you say that I can argue the preset theorem by the my preceding question using induction, right?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Anyway could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797598/any-linear-subspace-has-measure-zero), please?

Comment: No, nothing that complicated. It's just the obvious fact that a subset of a measure zero set also has measure zero.

Comment: Oh, yes! Clearly $\Bbb R^m\times\{t_{m+1}\}\times...\times\{t_{m+(n-m)}\}\subseteq\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{t_{m+(n-m)}\}$, right?

Comment: Exactly! I'd prefer to write $t_{m+(n-m)}$ as $t_n$ of course.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Okay, thanks too much for your assistance! Then could you help me too in the other question I showed?